# When are C++ operators really inlined?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, inline

From http://cs.brown.edu/~jak/proglang/cpp/stltut/tut.html and http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-qsort-vs-c-sort/, we find that using the STL's sorting mechanism is faster than C's qsort().

This is because the comparison function is "inlined". However, when using the compiler explorer at https://godbolt.org/ to inspect the output of the gcc compiler, I can't get any operators to actually become inlined. See [here](https://godbolt.org/g/JwVoDk) for an example, code given below:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myClass {
    public: 

    int key;
    int data;

    myClass(int k, int d) : key(k), data(d) {}

    inline bool operator<(myClass& other) {
        return key < other.key;
    }
};

main () {
    myClass c1(1,100), c2(2, 100);
    if (c1 < c2) cout << "True" << endl;
    else cout << "False" << endl;
}
```

The generated assembly code clearly makes a call to the `operator<` routine. The C++ compiler completely disregarded the `inline` keyword!

So when exactly *are* the operators inlined? This is the key to having faster sorting performance for example, but it would be nice to know how to take advantage of it whenever possible.

Comment: Did you turn optimization on?

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe that was all it took

Comment: Note: `inline` is redundant for member functions _defined_ inside a class body; they are automatically made `inline`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most compilers will not inline anything at all by default, because this can get in the way of debugging.  You need to enable optimizations.

gcc has a handful of [levels of optimizations](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) and many individually tweakable optimization settings, but even the simplest ["-O1" flag is enough](https://godbolt.org/g/6ekNs6) to cause your example to inline the `operator<` function.  (In fact, gcc actually realized it could determine the result of `operator<` at compile time, and was able to discard the `else` branch entirely!)